# Drag n Drop in a list view within is own columns (.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2005

I was just wondering, if I have a list view control, with *2* columns, and insert items to those columns, ex:

**Animal..................  Car**

Dog------------------   Ford Foucs

Cat-------------------  Subaru Rally

Bull------------------- Lambo Gallardo

Could I Select an item from One column and put in the other, ex. (Selecting lambo gallardo and drag drop it to 'Animal Column'

**Animal.................. Car**

Dog------------------   Ford Foucs

Cat-------------------  Subaru Rally

Bull
Lambo Gallardo

My GOAL is to NOT use a lot of listviews controls to interact from one col to another. Like a drag and drop function between multiple columns.

I have found a lot of examples but they only are between from one listview to another.
Have you tried This? I want to do this in vb.net.

Update 08/17/2011
To answer Jonsca:
I've done the long, dreadful solution: Create different list views controls.

```
Private Sub ListView_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles list1.DragDrop, _
list2.DragDrop, list3.DragDrop, listN.DragDrop
```

and some more for the Itemdrag and dragenter events. Got some ideas to kill this code?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution that worked for this?

Comment: Might be better if you edited your question to include some of the new code, at least easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could elect to monitor an `ItemDrag` event for when you hold down the mouse over the right column and drag, but the only problem is that the `sender` would be the entire `ListViewItem` (i.e., `Dog` *and* `FordFocus`).  This may not be a problem for two columns (for that case to move the item, you would delete the first `SubItem` (`FordFocus`) of that `ListViewItem` and start a new `ListViewItem` programmatically, with `FordFocus` as the text, and no subitems.

Thus, this would only work going from column 2 to column 1, and not in reverse.  With a third column, you would not be able to distinguish which of column 2 or column 3 you were selecting.